# How do I do this in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-literals

The following Unit Test passes in VB.Net

```
<Test()> _
Public Sub VB_XMLLiteral_SyntaxRocks_Test()
    Dim XML = <Doc>
                  <Level1>
                      <Item id="1"/>
                      <Item id="2"/>
                  </Level1>
                  <Level1>
                      <Item id="3"/>
                      <Item id="4"/>
                  </Level1>
              </Doc>
    Assert.AreEqual(4, XML.<Level1>.<Item>.Count)
End Sub
```

**How do I assert the same thing in C#?**

To clarify, I 'd like to know how to express...

```
XML.<Level1>.<Item>
```

...in C#

Comment: Is your Q about the Assert() or about the XML literal?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/140505)

Comment: XML Literal. I need to know how to replace "XML.<Level1>.<Item>" in C#

Comment: There is no equivalent in C# - XML literals are a VB.NET feature. You can use LINQ to XML.

Comment: @Oded Seriously?! You're saying that C# cannot retrieve this information? Can't be true.

Comment: @Oded: but questions about specific features should be OK.

Comment: I am saying that you can't use this notation. I didn't say it is not possible.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - True enough, though the initial question read like a translation request.

Comment: Em...Cool VB.NET syntax for xml.

Comment: The original question was posted as an unambiguous unit test. It was done this way to explain very clearly what the expectations of the code were. The need for this has been proven because below 2 answers are provided (Danny, Henk thanks very much for those). In one case the answer is wrong because the count is 2 rather than 4.

Comment: @Oded I'm curious what you would have had me do instead? I have passed this code through 3 separate code translation pages, and none of them had a clue what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Assert.AreEqual(4, XML.Elements("Level1").Elements("Item").Count());
```

And of course `XML` needs to be an `XElement` (that's what a VB literal produces too)

Comment: Yes, the first call needs to be Elements, not Element.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML:

```
var XML = new XElement("Doc",
    new XElement("Level1",
        new XElement("Item", 
            new XAttribute("Id", 1)),
        new XElement("Item", 
            new XAttribute("Id", 2))),
    new XElement("Level1",
        new XElement("Item", 
            new XAttribute("Id", 3)),
        new XElement("Item", 
            new XAttribute("Id", 4))));

Assert.AreEqual(4, 
   (from element in XML.Elements("Level1").Elements("Item")
    select element).Count());
```